# asp.net MVC User Friends LazyLoad

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, lazy-loading

If i try to use code first,
The User Class:

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public Guid ID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "You must pick a user name")]
    [DisplayName("User Name")]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string FullName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "You give a valid email address")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }        
    [Required]
    public DateTime CreateAt { get; set; }

    public string Image { get; set; }

    public bool RemeberMe { get; set; }

    public bool Dummy { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserFriend> Friends { get; set; }
 }
```

The UserFriend Class: - hold the relationship between users

```
public class UserFriend
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0), ForeignKey("User")]
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1), ForeignKey("Friend")]
    public Guid FriendId { get; set; }
    public User Friend { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

}
```

User Repository:

```
public class UserRepository : IUserRepository
{
    public User GetUserByName(string userName)
    {
        return context.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Username == userName);
    }
}
```

if i try to user this methods:

```
var userRepo = new UserRepository(new DataContext());
User user = userRepo.GetUserByName(User.Identity.Name);
```

PROBLEM: user.Friends.first().Friend return null
if i got it right my lazy load not working.

help please...

link to the project - https://github.com/RanDahan/barker

Comment: then show us the configuration related to the dbcontext

Comment: does user.identity.name have a value?  where is this being called?  in the action method or somewhere else?

Comment: yes, the user details works. if i type user.Friends.first().User i can see my details just the friend param is NULL.

Answer (score 0):

In the contructor of *User* class you should create new instance of *Friends* collection

```
Friends = new HashSet<UserFriend>()
```

Also, i think navigation properties in *UserFirends* should also have been declared as virtual.